# Building a menu and scheduler for a thermostat (rotary encoder for input, LCD screen)

Tags: software, arduino, time

I'm building an advanced thermostat on an arduino with the following goals:

- Use a rotary encoder (with pushbutton) as the only input device
- Use LCD display (standard 16x2)
- Use a real time clock
- Ability to schedule temperature changes
- Ability to 'ramp' between changes (ex: start at 45 degF, end at 50degF 3 days later with a linear increase between start and end date)

I have much of this project finished but where I've stalled out is building a 'scheduler' function and finding a good menu method. Can someone please suggest a function that would work as a scheduler and give some examples of a menu that might work well with this project?

Comment: Could you provide more details about what type of menu are you thinking of ? What requirements are you trying to fulfill ?

Answer (score 2):

For the scheduler, use the [Time](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/time) library. Maintain an array that mentions what change must happen when (create your own protocol for this, for example take "2000/40" to mean "change the thermostat to 40 at 20:00").

Now, in your main loop, set up `loop()` with a wait period of a second or so. (Since you're taking input as well, you cannot afford to have a longer wait period). Now, just compare your array values with the stuff returned by `hour()` and `minute()`, and trigger the changes as needed.

Ramping is also easy, just divvy up the temperature change by every hour. So, the ramp from 45 to 50 in 3 days, just set the Arduino to increase the temperature by 1 every 14 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of [arduino-menusystem](https://github.com/jonblack/arduino-menusystem), a library for building a menu system on the arduino. Below is an example (there are more in the repository):

```
#include <MenuSystem.h>

// Menu variables
MenuSystem ms;
Menu mm("");
MenuItem mm_mi1("Level 1 - Item 1 (Item)");
MenuItem mm_mi2("Level 1 - Item 2 (Item)");
Menu mu1("Level 1 - Item 3 (Menu)");
MenuItem mu1_mi1("Level 2 - Item 1 (Item)");

// Example variables
bool bRanCallback = false;
bool bForward = true;

// Menu callback function
// In this example all menu items use the same callback.

void on_item1_selected(MenuItem* p_menu_item)
{
  Serial.println("Item1 Selected");
  bRanCallback = true;
  bForward = true;
}

void on_item2_selected(MenuItem* p_menu_item)
{
  Serial.println("Item2 Selected");
  bRanCallback = true;
}

void on_item3_selected(MenuItem* p_menu_item)
{
  Serial.println("Item3 Selected");
  bRanCallback = true;
  bForward = false;
}

// Standard arduino functions

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Menu setup
  mm.add_item(&mm_mi1, &on_item1_selected);
  mm.add_item(&mm_mi2, &on_item2_selected);
  mm.add_menu(&mu1);
  mu1.add_item(&mu1_mi1, &on_item3_selected);
  ms.set_root_menu(&mm);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("");

  // Display the menu
  Serial.println(ms.get_current_menu()->get_selected()->get_name());

  // Simulate using the menu by walking over the entire structure.
  ms.select();

  if (bRanCallback)
  {
    if (bForward)
      ms.next();
    else
      ms.prev();
    bRanCallback = false;
  }

  // Wait for two seconds so the output is viewable
  delay(2000);
}
```

There's more information on the above GitHub page and also in the blog post [Arduino menu system library](http://blog.humblecoder.com/arduino-menu-system-library/).